# Analyse Flutter App Size Command not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

I am running the following commands to build the app bundle and analyze the size. I tried all the following commands but I am getting an error.

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm --analyze-size
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm64 --analyze-size
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-x64 --analyze-size
```

Error:

```
Could not find an option named "analyze-size".
```

Answer (score 0):

*it has to be as follows,*

```
flutter build appbundle --analyze-size --target-platform <architecture>
```

*architecture as you prefer Ex: android-arm64*

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your flutter version using this 2 command flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade after run your command to Analyse Flutter App